# Javascript - get number of cases in switch case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Is it possible to get the number of cases in a switch case statement in Javascript?

So for something like this

```
showError: function (status) {
        var message = '';

        //If the error comes from the browser's routing sys (the event parameter is the failed route), default to a 404 error
        if (typeof status === 'string') {
            status = 404;
        }

        //Determines the appropriate error message
        switch (status) {
            case 404:
                message = 'the page could not be found'; 
                break;

            case 500:
                message = 'internal server error';
                break; 
        }

        //Renders the view-less error template
        region.show(new Backbone.View());
        region.el.innerHTML = Marionette.TemplateCache.get(TemplIds.error)({message: message});
    },
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Since building a `switch` implies your beforehand knowledge of the options to treat, I don't find any case in which this would apply.

Comment: Why would this be helpful to know? It seems like this could be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I need to test code which is using a `switch`, however if anyone decides to add another case, there is no way the test will fail and force that person to add another test suit for the new case. I am simply trying to make sure that I cover all scenarios of testing the code.

Comment: This sounds like you should try to use a factory pattern instead of using switch statements - but without a little pseudo code there is no way to really help you here

Comment: Unfortunately I did not write the code, but I still need to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript `switch` and `case` are keyword logical operators and do not have a prototype or are introspectable by the javascript engine. However, `functions` are dynamic objects so if you put a switch statement within a function, then you can call `toString()` on that function to evaluate the function's contents like this:

```
var fn = function(value){
  switch(value){
    case "A": 
      return "Apple";
    case "B":
      return "Banana";
  }
};

var fnToString = fn.toString();
var fnBody = fnToString.match(/function[^{]+\{([\s\S]*)\}$/)[1];
var count = fnBody.match(/case/g).length; //should equal 2
```

Note: The regex is error prone, but gives you a gist of the strategy. I'll let you get fancy with the regex to find out how many times the word `case` occurs.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I knew it was a silly question to ask, so I appreciate your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. It's not that silly. Sometimes people have a hard time seeing out of the box.

Comment: Be careful, because it's not that easy, this can easily give incorrect results as the text `case` can be anywhere here. For example `"Apple"` to `"Apple case"`, would give an incorrect result of `3`.

Comment: Yea, would definitely suggest finding a more bullet proof way to match the 'case' occurrences. I just wanted to prove that it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know how many cases why don't you replace case with:

```
case_tot_nr=0
if ()
{ ... }
case_tot_nr++;
if()
{ ... }
case_tot_nr++;
if()
{ ... }
case_tot_nr++;
...
```

I can't image the usefulness of this, anyway, imho, your question is weird.

Comment: I fail to see how this is any different than a switch statement. The control would still need to enter the condition to increment the atomic counter variable. Besides, `case` is a keyword so you cannot name a variable that.

Comment: You're right, `case` is a keyword and i used only in a conceptual way. At first i thought he had access to the editing of code, so i suggested a redesign of it to count the number of total cases (according to the number of conditions). Anyway only later did I realized wich his aim was, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by bruteforcing: feed function with all possible values and analyze changes. Not all changes can be detectable, but if you know source and can edit it - this is trivial to adjust 'case's to help you.