# searching particular value from switch case javascript code

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, javascript-objects

I have got this below code on my alert box or say any variable.
    Here i just need to change the values in product to other values as such 'Tremfya','Remicade', dynamically.
i need to get these values for a particualr product like "linename" and "wheretonavigate" .
    How to define the javascript function for that.

```
function roadmaplist(product){
    var product = '#~Product~#';
    var PatientRoadMapList;
    switch (product) 
    {
        case 'Tremfya':
        {
            PatientRoadMapList = 
            [
                {
                    "linename" : "Initiate Prior Authorization",
                    "whereToNavigate" : "InsuranceCoverage"
                },
                {
                    "linename" : "Instant Benefits Investigation",
                    "whereToNavigate" : "InsuranceCoverage"
                },
                {
                    "linename" : "Check Eligibility and Enroll Patient into Savings Program",
                    "whereToNavigate" : "SavingsProgram"
                },
                {
                    "linename" : "Enroll Patient into PsO Simple",
                    "whereToNavigate" : "TreatmentSupport"
                },
                {
                    "linename" : "Upload Signed Prescription",
                    "whereToNavigate" : "InsuranceCoverage"
                }
            ];
            break;          
        }

        case 'Remicade':
        {
            PatientRoadMapList = 
            [
                {
                    "linename" : "Initiate Prior Authorization",
                    "whereToNavigate" : "InsuranceCoverage"
                },
                {
                    "linename" : "Instant Benefits Investigation",
                    "whereToNavigate" : "InsuranceCoverage"
                },
                {
                    "linename" : "Check Eligibility and Enroll Patient into Savings Program",
                    "whereToNavigate" : "SavingsProgram"
                }
            ];
            break;          
        }

    return PatientRoadMapList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function and pass the expr value to that function.

i.e

```
function fruits(fruit) {
         var expr = fruit;
         ....
         // your code here
         ....
    }
```

call that function from where you want to call.
i.e

```
alert(fruits("Papayas"));
```

or

```
var result = fruits("mango");
```

```js
function fruits(fruit) {
  var expr = fruit;
    switch(expr) {
      case 'banana':
        return 'your banana';
         break;
      default:
        return 'not found';
     }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <div>
  <input value ="click" type="button" onclick =alert(fruits('banana')); >
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: actually my code is in alert box,how to create a function with alert box.

Comment: completely new to javascript,any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: no need to create function in alert box. You just need to call that function from alert box. i.e alert(fruits("yourvalue"));

Comment: no,no try to understand..this line 'function fruits(fruit) {' is not there in alert box,only the rest of the code is there in alert box. I need to incorporate the rest of the code in javascript function which i am not able to do...hope u got the question/issue.

Comment: I got your question. Why are you putting the REST of the code.It is just simple. Create a function where you want and call that inside your alert. Thats all.

Comment: no like the of the code is coming from backend/class and stored inside the variable say 'br',and i am just doing alert(br),so how to create a function with br.

Comment: you can't. I have added a code snippet. see that. And from backend brought the value not the whole function.

Comment: thnx again for guiding me. i am posting the exact javascript function kindly guide me in that,plz

Comment: you can add call in your alert box i.e alert(roadmaplist(Tremfya)); or alert(roadmaplist(abc)); where abc is a variable that can store diff values.

Comment: i tried alert(roadmaplist('Tremfya')); its undefined actually

Comment: where did you defined roadmaplist?

Comment: it worked this tym using alert(PatientRoadMapList[0].listname);

Comment: one more question can i fetch the list of case names such as 'banana','oranges','papaya' etc. rite now this is the urgent thing for me.plz.

Comment: you can use for loop for that and pass the index. i.e alert(PatientRoadMapList[i].listname);

Comment: yeah got that but i need the case names like 'tremfya','stelara' etc.

Comment: PatientRoadMapList[i].listname will return something inside PatientroadMapList

Comment: fn.toString().match(/function[^{]+\{([\s\S]*)\}$/)[1].match(/case '/g) is returning me five times case '

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364691/javascript-get-number-of-cases-in-switch-case for referenece